# select all data beginning from the first of the month sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get data going back three months for monthly reports. I got to the point where i can get all the data. The problem is that it goes back 3 months based on the current date.

**Example:** If today is 7th of November it will give me the data up until the 7th of August. 
I need it to give me the data going back three months but starting from the first of the month.

**Example:** today is the 7th of November, I'll need the data starting from the 1st of August.

Here is the code I'm using to get the data from three months back:

```
SELECT * FROM 'closed_wo_journal' WHERE date_time_stamp > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```

Answer (score 1):

The `date_trunc` function is just what the doctor ordered:

```
SELECT *
FROM   closed_wo_journal
WHERE  date_time_stamp > DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', CURDATE() - INTERVAL '3 MONTH')
```

Comment: I wasn't aware MySQL had a `date_trunc()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is logic to get the first of the month, three months ago:

```
SELECT j.*
FROM closed_wo_journal j
WHERE j.date_time_stamp >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL (1 - DAY(CURDATE()) DAY) ) - INTERVAL 3 MONTH )
```